# open csv collection and continuous array

Tags: java, parsing, csv, opencsv

i dont quite understand by the given eg on opencsv site on how to use collection here List,eg is:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));**
List myEntries = reader.readAll();**
```

I tried accessing a member of the List for eg `System.out.println(myEntries.get(2))` but it gives me something like `d1e604` and when i tested for existence of an element

```
boolean b = myEntries.contains("the element");** and it returns false.
```

what do i need to do to access the tokenized Strings?

by using readNext(), the elements are separated by "\n" and i want to assign the elements in a continuous no. of array.

```
while((tokened = reader.readNext()) != null){
    int numOfArray = tokened.length;
    System.out.println("number of items:"+ numOfArray) ;
    for (int i = 0;i < numOfArray;i++) {
    System.out.println("     tokenNo[" + i + "]:  " + tokened[i]);

   }
 }
```

Comment: `myEntries` contains arrays of string. thus the contains() can never return true. Whats the result of the code at the end?

Comment: @ZeissS: strings indexed by no of element of a column.say a column has 3 elements,array is 0 to 2 and back again to 0 for the next column.im trying to arrange this separated strings into one single string indexed from 0 to end of column in a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed a little fact about CSV. CSV is about lines AND columns. `readNext()` returns an array of strings representing a line.  So I would guess, readAll() returns a list of string[].

Comment: about the readAll(),none of the data was read as I described above.isn't the tokenized String should be available once readAll() executed?

Answer (score 1):

Each element of your List myEntries is a String[].
i.e. That is an array of String.
that means you need a cast.

```
String[] entry = (String[]) myEntries.get(2);
```

Also -

```
System.out.println(myEntries.get(2)) but it gives me something like d1e604.
```

That's because the toString method is not properly overridden. That's the default behavior of the toString method as implemented in the Object class.